# Curl authorization

Tags: curl, https

I have spring security with https settings.

I'm seeing an unexpected behavior when trying to run curl GET on a URL in a secure way.

When curl first sends a request to the server, it does it with no authorization data (why? I specifically added it). Then, the server reply with Authentication Error (401). 
The client then re-transmits the request, this time with authorization data, and the server replies properly with the required data.

Any idea why this happens?

Curl command:

> curl -v --insecure --anyauth --user username:password -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET localhost:8443/myresource

**Request 1:**

```
> GET /myresource HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.3 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.3 NSS/3.13.1.0 zlib/1.2.5 libidn/1.19 libssh2/1.2.7
> Host: localhost:8443
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Type: application/json
```

**Response 1:**

```
< HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=B56A7F49E715795B5D1158DB192710AA; Path=/myresource ; Secure; HttpOnly
< WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="Protected", qop="auth", nonce="MTM0Njg2MjYwMjY0ODozNDk5ZDkxNTYxNjMxMDJmNDA4MWQ1NTBmZjk5OGQ5Nw=="
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Length: 1119
< Date: Wed, 05 Sep 2012 16:29:52 GMT
```

**Request 2:**

```
> GET /myresource HTTP/1.1
> Authorization: Digest username="username", realm="Protected", nonce="MTM0Njg2MjYwMjY0ODozNDk5ZDkxNTYxNjMxMDJmNDA4MWQ1NTBmZjk5OGQ5Nw==", uri="/myresource", cnonce="ODczNjg0", nc=00000001, qop="auth", response="58faded9ae5f639ba0056fb86edca71f"
> User-Agent: curl/7.21.3 (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.21.3 NSS/3.13.1.0 zlib/1.2.5 libidn/1.19 libssh2/1.2.7
> Host: localhost:8443
> Accept: application/json
> Content-Type: application/json
```

**Response 2:**

```
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=37F375C5663C4A049D95D49C7C1CF0FD; Path=/myresource ; Secure; HttpOnly
< Content-Type: application/json
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Date: Wed, 05 Sep 2012 16:29:52 GMT
```

Comment: Please share your curl command and relevant output. You can also use -v option for more info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [man curl](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html):

> --anyauth
>
> (HTTP) Tells curl to figure out authentication method by itself, and
>   use the most secure one the remote site claims to support. This is
>   done by first doing a request and checking the response-headers, thus
>   possibly inducing an extra network round-trip. This is used instead of
>   setting a specific authentication method, which you can do with
>   --basic, --digest, --ntlm, and --negotiate.
>
> Note that using --anyauth is not recommended if you do uploads from
>   stdin, since it may require data to be sent twice and then the client
>   must be able to rewind. If the need should arise when uploading from
>   stdin, the upload operation will fail.

You should use --digest instead of --anyauth.

Comment: using --digest will make no difference here as the information in the 401 is needed.

Answer (score 3):

Digest authentication cannot take place without the first 401 response from the server.

Ie: The server replies to the first request with:

```
WWW-Authenticate: Digest realm="Protected", qop="auth", nonce="MTM0Njg2MjYwMjY0ODozNDk5ZDkxNTYxNjMxMDJmNDA4MWQ1NTBmZjk5OGQ5Nw=="
```

The client needs this information before it can assemble a valid digest authentication request. Digest requires the nonce and the op method to use in order to provide a valid

```
response="58faded9ae5f639ba0056fb86edca71f"
```

as shown in the second request.

So in short you can't do a digest request without without first getting the 401 as you don't have enough information to assemble the response without it.